# How to safely sell and transfer a web domain?

Tags: online-payment, selling

Let's imagine the following situation: You have a domain like example.com and someone is interested in buying it. You as the owner of the domain are located in the European Union and the interested party is an American company.

The domain transfer is done by an so-called [AuthCode](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/auth-2013-05-03-en). You get this code from the registrar and hand it over to the customer, who initiate the transfer process. You will be asked to confirm the transfer. That's how I understand the technical process of transfering a web domain.

To all this I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it advisable to set up a contract? Should this contract send by snail mail, so it's valid?
2. When is it appropriate moment to receive the money? Before handing over the AuthCode?
3. When is the moment to hand over the AuthCode?
4. What is the best way to receive the money? (transaction fee should be < 2%)
5. Are there other things, which I should pay attentiont to, if I want to sell a web domain safely?

Comment: There are a lot of scammers out there, so be careful. Did they ask you to get a valuation of your domain using a specific service or did they ask for any other upfront costs either to you or a third party? If they suggest an escrow service, make sure it's legit. Anyone can set up an "escrow" website and steal your money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your question regarding contracts, I'd say it's like anything else. Having a contract always helps to protect both parties in the event of a dispute. Given that you both are in different countries, it may be a major headache to try to sue and enforce contractual rights. So, it's up to you and your attorney(s) to decide if a contract is worthwhile.

I'd say your best bet is to use an escrow service. That would be the safest way to do it. An escrow service assures both parties that the transaction will proceed without any shenanigans.

Personally, if we're talking about a high value property, I'd have my attorneys draft a contract and use an escrow service.

Comment: There are several escrow services that specialize in domain name sales, and you can find them by Googling ["domain escrow service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=domain+escrow+service).